# How can I work with a database in Android?

Tags: android

How can I connect to and insert and select data from a database in Android?

Comment: Are you referring to a local SQLite database on the device, or a remote, full database like MySQL?

Answer (score 5):

There are too many examples of how to do it:

- [Android SQLite Basics: creating and
  using a database, and working with
  sqlite3](http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742)
- [Android Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)
- Also, the [NotePad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/index.html) in official developer's page is a good starting point.